# Manually added Authorization Role not working

Tags: authentication, blazor, authorization, claims

I have created a custom IClaimsTransformation class that gets a list of allowed groups from a config file. If the user is in one of the groups a claim is added. I can verify that the claim is getting added, but the user still does not have access to the page. If I decorate the Authorize attribute with a group name it works, but if I decorate it with my custom role that gets added if the user belongs to one of the groups in the config file it does not work.

```
 public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        
        PowerConfig.Initialize();

        var ci = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
        var re = ci.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.GroupSid || x.Type == ClaimTypes.PrimaryGroupSid).ToList();
        foreach (var item in re)
        {
            string account = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(item.Value).Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
            var roleClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, account);
            ci.AddClaim(roleClaim);

            foreach (var group in PowerConfig.ServerSettings.Authorization.ForwardsList)
            {
                if (account == group)
                {
                    ci.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Forwards"));
                }
            }

            foreach (var group in PowerConfig.ServerSettings.Authorization.ScheduledForwardsList)
            {
                if (account == group)
                {
                    ci.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "ScheduledForwards"));
                }
            }

        }
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

This works (using the actual group name):

```
@page "/forwards"

@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "POWERSOURCE\\PowerSource Admins")]
```

Active Forwards

This does not work

```
@page "/forwards"

@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Forwards")]
```

However if I set a breakpoint on the return result of the transformation class I can see that the claim "Forwards" was added right next to the role PowerSource Admins that does work. (see below)

[image]

The reason I have it setup this way is because I didn't want to hard code the groups that are allowed to access the page into the code. I thought it would be better to hard code a custom role, then give the user that role if they belong to the correct group based on a setting. If there is a better way to do this please let me know.

Also, the claimstransformer class runs 4 times. I assume this is by design but I just wondered why that is.

UPDATE:

Somebody just whispered in my ear to try a new Identity instead of updating the windows identity. I tried it and it worked. I don't understand why it didn't work before as all of the other roles were added by modifying the windows identity. Oh well, the below code works.

```
public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        
        PowerConfig.Initialize();

        var ci = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
        var ci2 = new ClaimsIdentity();
        var re = ci.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.GroupSid || x.Type == ClaimTypes.PrimaryGroupSid).ToList();
        foreach (var item in re)
        {
            string account = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(item.Value).Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
            
            foreach (var group in PowerConfig.ServerSettings.Authorization.ForwardsList)
            {
                if (account == group)
                {
                    ci2.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Forwards"));
                }
            }

            foreach (var group in PowerConfig.ServerSettings.Authorization.ScheduledForwardsList)
            {
                if (account == group)
                {
                    ci2.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "ScheduledForwards"));
                }
            }

        }

        principal.AddIdentity(ci2);

        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ci.AddClaim(...)` try `principal.Identity.AddClaim(...)`.

`ci` is assigned by value so you are adding claims to a copy of the identity from `principal`, so when you return `principal` it hasn't been changed.  In the second version you are modifying `ci2` and then adding it to `principal` before you return it, so that's why it works.

You could also skip `ci2` and put

```
principal.AddIdentity(ci);
```

in the same spot which should also work.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine a `ClaimsPrincipal` object you will see it can have multiple `ClaimsIdentity` objects - the `Identities` property.  In general you shouldn't modify the incoming `Identities`, just add new ones.  You can use this to add all sorts of information and claims (such as roles) to a `ClaimsPrincipal` without mutating the original `ClaimsIdentity`.

To demonstrate here's a very simple `ServerAuthenticationStateProvider` that adds the "Admin" and "User" roles to the user provided by the base class.

```cs
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : ServerAuthenticationStateProvider
{
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var authState = await base.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;
        user.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin") }));
        user.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User") }));

        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
    }
}
```

This user will be able to access pages with `@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "User")]` and `@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` set.